# TestNG setup issue- Cannot find class in classpath

Tags: selenium, testng

I am pretty new to TestNG framework. I did download TestNG from the link http://beust.com/eclipse. Post this I created a new Java Project named as MyProject and a new TestNG class file "NewTest". I did write a small piece of Code with @Test annotation to launch Firefox browser and navigate to Google. I tried searching the web for possible solutions to sort this issue but I am not able to find the low level steps on how this can be corrected. Please help.

**Output**

```
org.testng.TestNGException:  Cannot find class in classpath: NewTest
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
    at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
    at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:582)  
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:39)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:170)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:305)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:109)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)     
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move `Package1` inside `src` directory and run the code.

**Note:** Eclipse run `.java` files from `src` directory, and create `.class` files in `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I did not update my Eclipse for few months. I did navigate to Eclipse->Help->Check for updates->Completed installing all updates. Post this the test did run fine.